# Multiplying a char variable by int

Tags: java, char, logic

The below code :

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char ch =65;
        System.out.println(ch);
    }
}
```

generates the following output :

```
A
```

but the following code :

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       char ch =65;
       System.out.println(ch*1);
    }
}
```

generates the following output :

```
65
```

Why is that, Why Java doesn't convert back the int output from 'ch*1' to char ?

Comment: Why do you think it should? You multiply an int and a char. It seems more logical to me to get back an int than a char. And, regardless of what you find logical or not, the Java Language Specifications defines how such operations are done: char is promoted to an int, then the two ints are multiplied, and that gives an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you multiply a `char` by an `int`, the result is an `int`, not a `char`.

This means that `System.out.println(ch);` calls `println(char x)`, whereas `System.out.println(ch*1);` calls `println(int x)`.

`print(char)`, which is called by `println(char)` has this comment:

> Prints a character. The character is translated into one or more bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the write(int) method.

Answer (score 2):

Because `println` have multiple signature, and in your code you are calling two different methods :

the first println `println(ch);` call :

```
public void println(char x) {..}
```

and the second `println(ch*1);` call :

```
public void println(int x) {..}
```

because `ch*1` is an arithmetic operation which return an `int` not a `char`

Answer (score 0):

Cause you are doing a multiplication so Java automaticly convert into the numeric value of the char.

Answer (score 0):

In Java whenever an arithmetic operation involves two data types , the smaller type is converted to larger type . In your code when you performed :

(ch*1) whose data types are character and integer , larger type is integer so overloaded println(int x) is executed

In general , resultant data type obtained depends on operands type .

Please refer [Type conversion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-java-examples/) for further understanding . Hope this will clarify .